# how to reload tableview automatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

Hi I am doing a post screen where users add post and view them.This is the viewcontroller for viewing. I am getting information from firebase and reload that info to my table view cells everything is going perfect. However to reload the screen and see if my posts are up to date I need to close the application and run it again each time although I use .reloadData() function and it doesn't reload automatically after each posting. here is my code where do I do the mistake? or am I missing something?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.navcik.title = "Posts"
    tableView = UITableView(frame:view.bounds, style: .plain)
    view.addSubview(tableView)
    let cellnib = UINib(nibName: "postTableCell", bundle: nil)
    tableView.register(cellnib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "postCell")

    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.reloadData()
    observeposts()
}
func observeposts() {
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("posts").getDocuments { (snap, error) in
        var tempposts = [Post]()
        if error != nil {
            print("error:\(String(describing: error))")
        } else {
            for document in snap!.documents {
                if let dict = document.data() as? [String: Any] ,
                let username = dict["username"] as? String,
                let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                    let desc = dict["desc"] as? String {
                    let post = Post(id: "1", username: username, title: title, desc: desc)
                    tempposts.append(post)
                }

            }
            self.posts = tempposts
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
@IBOutlet weak var navcik: UINavigationItem!

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return posts.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "postCell", for: indexPath) as! postTableCell
    cell.set(post: posts[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}
```

Comment: where in your code the new posts are added please?

Comment: well in actually you need to implement pull to refresh in your tableView footer or  in cellForRowAtIndexPath at very last index you need to pull latest records and append them to your array. currently you have not implemented any mechanism for latest post.

Answer (score 1):

Well I just added a refresher and observed the posts there and reloaded, works perfect now.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 for document in snap!.documents {
            if let dict = document.data() as? [String: Any] ,
            let username = dict["username"] as? String,
            let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                let desc = dict["desc"] as? String {
                let post = Post(id: "1", username: username, title: title, desc: desc)
                tempposts.append(post)
            }
            tableView.reloadData()
        }
```