# iOS tableView not reloading until click, scroll, or switch tabbar items

Tags: ios, swift

I have this problem where (in several places) after executing an API call, the view does not refresh until a user action - like a btn click, tab bar switch, etc occurs. I have a feeling it is related to threading, but I can't seem to figure it out and I am new to iOS programming. I have tried different solutions with DispatchQueue etc, using it, and not using it. Trying to call setNeedsDisplay on the controller view. But no luck yet. The following is an example of code pulled right from one of my tab bar item view controllers:

```
 func getEmployeeUpdates(){

        self.showLoader()

        APIAdaptor.shared.getEmployeeUpdates(forEmployee: Session.shared.employee, completion: {


            (updates:[ScheduleUpdate]?, error:Error?) in



            guard error == nil else{

                DispatchQueue.main.async {

                    //  self.resetMainScreen()

                    self.hideLoader();

                }
                return
            }            

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.hideLoader();
                self.ScheduleUpdates = updates!
                self.tableView.reloadData();                

            }        

        })

    }

  func showLoader(){

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([

            activityIndicator!.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerXAnchor),

            activityIndicator!.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.tableView.centerYAnchor)])

        activityIndicator?.startAnimating();

    }



    func hideLoader(){

        print("Hiding");

        activityIndicator?.stopAnimating()

    }
```

I have attached two images. The first image is where the api call has finished (confirmed through testing) but the view is not refreshing. The loader is frozen. It should disappear after a call to hideLoader(). the second Image is after a click, or tab bar item switch.

I should also mention that in this example, as well as in other api calls the view will refresh eventually after completing, but only after a significant delay.

If anyone can help I would appreciate it very much!

[image: loaded, but not refreshing view][image: loaded, after click, refreshed]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to reload tableview automatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394927/how-to-reload-tableview-automatically)

Comment: Please show us `showLoader` and `hideLoader`. — Put a `print` statement after the second `hideLoader` call (the one that should be called if there is no error). Do the API call. Does the `print` print? If so, that proves that we are in the right place and `hideLoader` is indeed being called, so then we need to figure out why the loader is not in fact hiding.

Comment: @matt Yes, it prints. I have update the code with showLoader and hideLoader. also added following text "I should also mention that in this example, as well as in other api calls the view will refresh eventually after completing, but only after a significant delay."

Comment: So "Hiding" prints but we do not hide? That does sound like a threading problem. But I don't see the issue any more than you do. :) Have you got the main thread checker turned on? Have you tried running with the thread sanitizer turned on?

Comment: well I'm not sure why the table view isn't refreshing but I can confirm that `.stopAnimating()` isn't meant to hide the activity indicator.. you need to do `activityIndicator.hidesWhenStopped = true` at some point for that to happen

Comment: oh yikes I misread the docs, actually the default is true for that... yeah must be a threading thing :(. is `getEmployeeUpdates` called on the main thread? bc you're attempting to start the activityIndicator on that thread

Comment: @gadu thanks, I have it anyways at declaration

Comment: is there any other work that can be blocking the main thread.. does `self.ScheduleUpdates = updates!` trigger anything via didSet or other observers? I think @matt had the right idea with looking into the main thread, this def smells strongly of main thread misuse

Comment: @gadu getEmployeeUpdates and any other api call with this problem is called from the main thread. My understanding is that my api calls with URLSession.dataTask are on another thread, that is why I need to use DispatchQueue.main.async

Comment: @matt I have edited my scheme, turned thread checker on, selected pause on problems. No issues, No additional information in the log

Comment: could it be a problem with the simulator? I don't have any way to easily test on a device

Comment: @gadu No observables I don't think, unless they are inherent to arrays. I am not using didSet. updates is just an array of ScheduleUpdate class. i put a print statement after each line in the DispatchQueue closure, they all print almost immediately. But, the view doesn't refresh until after 4 - 6 seconds, or until click

Comment: It is certainly possible to be misled by the simulator if you're on an older slower machine. I had to stop using the simulator on my MacBook Pro (13-inch, Early 2011) because it just didn't update correctly (and now of course a modern version of Xcode won't run on it anyway). But you'd have to be using an old version of Xcode to see that; Xcode 11 simulator uses the GPU and is pretty accurate.

Comment: make sure you give tableviewdelegate and data source for view controller

Comment: @matt I am using xcode 10, and my machine is ok, but for reasons I can't get into, not as fast as it could be. However, I want to pick your brains on one more thought. This is stage 2 in development of this app. I didn't have this problem in stage 1. In stage1 I had my api calls operating inside of a view contoller which was embedded in a navigation controller. Now, in stage2 i have my api calls inside separate view controllers which  are embedded in a tab bar controller. Could this structural difference account for this problem? I am much more familiar with lifecycles in android.

Comment: I can't see (from what you've said) the tab bar controller would make any difference, though I might know more if you described what "i have my api calls inside separate view controllers" means. However Xcode 10 is exactly the version where the simulator became unusable on my machine and I had to resort to testing on the device only. Your suggestion that this might be a simulator issue is so brilliant and so likely, it seems to me you should just find out! Either whip out a device and run it there, or download Xcode 11 and try it there. Please let me know what transpires.

Comment: In previous attempts I haven't been able to get my test iPhone working. Due to my setup I cannot update my Mac OS, am stuck at a certain version of xcode, and restricted to what IPhone support files I have. Thanks to the WWW i was able to get IPhone 13.1  support files injected into my xcode package. Confirmed, it was the simulator. Thanks for all your help everyone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was a problem caused by the simulator on Xcode 10.1. If you run into this problem, try updating Xcode, or using a real device.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for reporting back. Your idea that the simulator might be misleading you here was inspired. Well done. With luck this Q&A will help others. Don't forget to accept your own answer when permitted to do so.